# Update SQLITE query

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update

I need only `one table` and only `one row` and `update` new displacement in it.

For **Creating** Table

```
 private static void createAllTables(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    database.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + IN_RIDE_DATA + " ("
            + TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE + " TEXT, "
            + USER_ID + " TEXT" + ");");

}
```

For Updating Table (I remove previous displacement and then insert it new displacement, But i Want to update already existing displacement)

```
public void insertDisplacement(String id, String displacement) {
    try {
        deleteDriverLocData();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NewDatabaseForInRideData.USER_ID, id);
        contentValues.put(NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE, displacement);
        database.insert(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_DATA, null, contentValues);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For getting displacement

```
 public String getDisplacement() {
    try {
        String[] columns = new String[]{NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE};
        Cursor cursor = database.query(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_DATA, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String totaldisplacement = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE));
        return totaldisplacement;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

For deleting displacement

```
public void deleteDriverLocData() {
    try {
        database.delete(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_DATA, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, you told what you want, you showed how you do it. But now tell us what is the problem.

Comment: @VladMatvienko want to use update query inseted of insert query

Comment: ok, and what makes a problem for you to switch to update query?

Comment: want to use update query

Comment: and what is the problem for you to write code to use update query?

Comment: because i think it will delete Table and then again create table and then insert the displacement in it
instead of this i use update query

Answer (score 0):

You have to make object of `contentvalue`

```
 ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("displacement1","231"); //These Fields should be your String 
          values of actual column names
            cv.put("displacement2","21");
            cv.put("displacement3","21");
```

after this, you can use update query which SQLite provides

```
database.update(TableName, cv, "USER_ID  ="+id, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following or something along the lines of the following could be used as a replacement for the `insertDisplacement` method :-

```
public void insertOrUpdateDisplacement(String id, String displacement) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE, displacement);
    String whereclause = NewDatabaseForInRideData.USER_ID + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};

    Cursor csr = database.query(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_DATA,
            null,
            whereclause,
            whereargs,
            null,null,null
    );
    if (csr.getCount() < 1) {
        deleteDriverLocData();
        contentValues.put(NewDatabaseForInRideData.USER_ID, id);
        database.insert(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_DATA, null, contentValues);
    } else {
        //deleteDriverLocData(); ????? Not sure if required or not.
        database.update(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_DATA,contentValues,whereclause,whereargs);
    }
    csr.close();
}
```

This will insert if there is no row (I assume for the user_id) otherwise it will update the displacement column of the existing row.

Comment: when i getDisplacement() error received
Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: That's because you are using `moveToFirst` without checking the return which will be false if there is no row in the Cursor hence the message, as the Cursor has no rows i.e. size 0. However, that's irrelevant to the question you asked, the check for the displacement/row existing is part of the `insertOrUpdateDisplacement` method.